# getting an error while submitting, stating 'object not found!'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am very new to this laravel framework.
And I am stuck here. I got an error like **'Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.36'**
**that's my form:i am just trying to insert data in database**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <form method="posts" action="/posts">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter the title">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    @stop

   </body>
   </html>
```

**and my controller:**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Post;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;

    class PostController extends Controller
    {
    public function index() {
        return "lets see whether it is working or not".$id;
            }
        }

    public function create() {
        return view('posts.create');
            }

    public function show(){
        //return view();
    }
    public function edit(){
        //
        }
    public function update(Request $Request,$id){
    //
    } 

    public function destroy($id){
        //
        }
    public function store(Request $request){
        Post::create($request->all());

            }

       }
```

**and finally my route:**

```
    Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

Comment: `<form method="post" action="/posts">` try this

Comment: oh i forgot to do fix it back

Comment: but still then it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method to 'post' and the action to `{{ route('posts.store') }}`. Also be sure to add the  `@csrf` blade directive in your from to include the csrf token.

So your form will look like:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter the title">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you i did it and now i am getting an error:
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
Route [posts.store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\posts\create.blade.php)

Comment: That route should be defined when you use `Route::resource('posts','PostController');`. When you execute `php artisan route:list` in your terminal, what does it output?

Comment: i think have handled this

Comment: POST method for posts.store and GETHEAD for posts.create

Comment: Could you show the raw output from that command? And your form.

Comment: do i have to write something in my model? because now my error is pointing at my model i.e. Post.php

Comment: FatalErrorException in Post.php line 9:
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting ',' or ';'. But my model is empty: <?php
 // namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Routing

class Post extends Model
{
    //
    
}

Comment: Place a `;` after `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Routing`